# how do i create this expandable cell without nib? swift 4

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift4, cells

hey i have a tableview with images and some text labels the whole cell is 400 in height and i want to extend it to 700 when i click the cell to make the user see more information of the cell so i wrote this code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if isExpanded && self.selectedIndex == indexPath{

        return 700
    }

    return 400.0
}

var selectedIndex:IndexPath?
var isExpanded = false

func didExpandCell() {

    self.isExpanded = !isExpanded

    self.postsTableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndex!], with: .automatic)

}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.selectedIndex = indexPath
    self.didExpandCell()

}
```

but this code requires a .xib file off the Cell, i have tryed to run the app without the code below but it doesnt work and i have tryed it with it and it doesnt work because i need a .xib file for the cell so i was wondering if it is possible that someone could help me with this and just explain how i can this cells epandable without this .xib file of the cell

```
func unnesseryNibFile(){

    //this code goes in the viewDidLoad func and it is required to have a .xib file of the Cell protoype

    let nib = UINib.init(nibName: "postTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    self.postsTableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
}
```

here is my 'cellForRowAt'

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell
    // Configure the cell...
    let post = self.posts[indexPath.row] as! [String: AnyObject]
    cell.locationLabel.text = post["location"] as? String
    cell.usernameLabel.text = post["username"] as? String
    cell.titleLabel.text = post["title"] as? String
    cell.contentTextView.text = post["content"] as? String
        if let imageName = post["image"] as? String {
            let imageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("images/\(String(describing: imageName))")
                imageRef.getData(maxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        //succeful
                        let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                        cell.postImageView.image = image
                        }else{
                        //Not Succesful
                        print("error Downloading The Image\(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
        }
    })
}
    return cell
}
```

thanks for your time. :)

Comment: If you don't want to register cell from nib you need to link it in storyboard. its batter if you can provide your `cellForRow(atIndextPath)` implementation.

Comment: @HussaanS i updated the qustion it looks like this because iam using firebase and not just a usuall array

Comment: It has nothing to do with the firebase. I believe you have this PostTableViewCell designed in a xib, All you have to do is to go to view controller in storyboard add a UITableViewCell and copy past UI components in it according to the requirement. Then assign PostTableViewCell class to it. It will be linked to postTableView.

Comment: Everything is a already working fine i just want to make The cell expandable @HussaanS

Comment: If I am understanding it correctly, you want it work without nib. My previous comment is about, how to get rid of nib. Otherwise You're implementation is correct. It will have some logical error for more then one cell but this is not your concern right now.

Comment: Yes That is correct but things are working as it should i just want to imploment The extra function to make The cell height to 700 and back to 400 for everything time The user clicks The cell

Comment: How many cells are you expecting to have here? If its dynamic you should add a `var expanded = false` in `PostTableViewCell`. Invert and assign its value to `self.isExpanded` before reloading a row.

Comment: well its going to be alot of cells sense its up to the user on how many there is going to be @HussaanS